# Oauth2 grant type client_credentials use case in the matter of microservices

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0, microservices, spring-security-oauth2

My use case is probably ordinary, but I did not find a proper explanation. For example, a client (browser) calls my service to create a user, that service has to call another service that should create a user in its own database too.

I use spring WebClient which calls other services. I read that grant type client_credentials is used when communication running between 2 machines. For example, when one service has cron job synchronizing data between services at midnight.

I would like to know if I should take the token which was obtained from the client or should I let WebClient call the authorization server with the grant type client_credentials because it is machine-to-machine communication and this token use to call the mentioned service?

Comment: As second service has protected endpoints under OAuth server and your first service is obtaining the token before submitting the request for adding the user. You already have the information at service one passed from client end so you should let the webclient to handle the requests with client_credentials grant type from service one.

Comment: Thank you @harry for your opinion.